# Is there any way to reshape more than one image together in python for NMF?

Tags: scikit-learn, scikit-image, nmf

I´m new with `Nmf` with python . I´m trying to create a list of images to then get the components. Here is the code:

```
from skimage import color
from skimage import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f=color.rgb2gray(io.imread('f.jpg'))
e=color.rgb2gray(io.imread('e.jpg'))


images2= (e,f)

from sklearn.decomposition import NMF
model=NMF(n_components=2)
features=model.fit_transform(images2)
```

And then the next error appears:

```
Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

Comment: You need to flatten each images into a vector (1d).

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation. The design matrix (argument of `NMF.fit`) needs to be of size `(n_samples,n_features)`. Which means that you need to flatten your images.

Try:

```py
from skimage import color
from skimage import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f=color.rgb2gray(io.imread('f.jpg'))
e=color.rgb2gray(io.imread('e.jpg'))


images2= (e,f)

#flattening
images2 = np.array(images2).reshape(2,-1)

from sklearn.decomposition import NMF
model=NMF(n_components=2)
features=model.fit_transform(images2)
```